# TFS 2017 - rename \ change default Git repository

Tags: git, tfs, git-branch

We are using TFS 2017 update 3.

I am looking for a way to rename or change our default Git repo branch from `master` to `main`.

Yes, I can go manually, one by one and update them, and also do it manually for all new repos, but I would like to find out if there is a better way of doing it and also if there is a way to make sure that new repos will have `main` branch as default and not `master`.

Since TFS stores data in SQL, maybe there is some query that will allow me to find all repos without `main` branch being default one.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to find out if there is a better way of doing it and also if there is a way to make sure that new repos will have main branch as default and not master.

If you do not want to manually to change the default branch from `master` to `main`, you could try to use the REST API:

[Update repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/update?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0)：

```
PATCH https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}?api-version=5.0
```

With payload:

```
{
    "defaultBranch": "refs/heads/{branchName}"
}
```

If you want to fully automate for all repos, first we need create scripts to invoke the REST API [Repositories - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) to check if the default branch is `main` or not.

If not, we could use REST API [Initial commit (Create a new branch)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#initial-commit-(create-a-new-branch)) to create the main branch.

At latest, we use the REST API to update the default branch to `mian`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was trying to implement it, but unfortunately, as I just find out from Microsoft, REST API is available only starting from TFS 2018 update 2 and I am using TFS 2017 update 3.

Regards, Mikhail.